# Python PIL - Resizing Images Without Keeping Aspect Ratio

Tags: python, image, opencv, video, python-imaging-library

So I've got a Python script that takes a bunch of images in a folder, and puts them together into arrays (like [this](http://www.photojoiner.net/)). I also have another script that takes the frames of a video and puts them together in arrays. The problem is, the one that takes the frames from a video creates black bars between the images.

Here is the **correct image** made using the first script, which uses JPEGS:
[image: Correct image made using JPEGS]

Here is the **wrong image** made using the second script, which uses video frames:
[image: Incorrect image made using video frames]

Here is the script that makes the **correct** first image:

```
import Image
import glob
import os


name = raw_input('What is the file name (excluding the extension) of your video that was converted using FreeVideoToJPGConverter?\n')
x_res = int(raw_input('What do you want the width of your image to be (in pixels)?\n'))
y_res = int(raw_input('What do you want the height of your image to be (in pixels)?\n'))
rows = int(raw_input('How many rows do you want?\n'))
columns = int(raw_input('How many columns do you want?\n'))

images = glob.glob('./' + name + ' (*)/' + name + '*.jpg')
new_im = Image.new('RGB', (x_res,y_res))
x_cntr = 0
y_cntr = 0

if not os.path.exists('./' + name + ' Output/'):
    os.makedirs('./' + name + ' Output/')


for x in xrange(0,len(images),1):
    if x%(rows*columns) == 0:
        new_im.save('./' + name + ' Output/' + str(x) + '.jpg')
        new_im = Image.new('RGB', (x_res,y_res))
        y_cntr = 0
        x_cntr = 0
        print str(round(100*(float(x)/len(images)), 1)) + "% Complete"
    elif x%rows == 0:
        x_cntr = 0
        y_cntr = y_cntr + y_res/columns
    elif x%1 == 0:
        x_cntr = x_cntr + x_res/rows
    im = Image.open(images[x])
    im = im.resize((x_res/rows + x_res%rows, y_res/columns + y_res%columns), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    new_im.paste(im, (x_cntr, y_cntr))
```

Here is the script that makes the **incorrect** second image:

```
import cv2, Image, os


name = raw_input('Video File (With Extension): ')
x_res = int(raw_input('Image Width (Pixels): '))
y_res = int(raw_input('Image Height (Pixels): '))
rows = int(raw_input('Number of Rows: '))
columns = int(raw_input('Number of Columns: '))


vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(name)
success,im = vidcap.read()
frames = int(vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
new_im = Image.new('RGB', (x_res, y_res))
x_cntr = 0
y_cntr = 0

print str(frames) + " Frames to Join"

if not os.path.exists('./' + name + ' Output/'):
    os.makedirs('./' + name + ' Output/')


for x in xrange(0,frames,1):
    if x%(rows*columns) == 0:
        new_im.save('./' + name + ' Output/' + str(x) + '.jpg')
        new_im = Image.new('RGB', (x_res,y_res))
        y_cntr = 0
        x_cntr = 0
        print str(round(100*(float(x)/frames), 1)) + "% Complete"
    elif x%rows == 0:
        x_cntr = 0
        y_cntr = y_cntr + y_res/columns
    elif x%1 == 0:
        x_cntr = x_cntr + x_res/rows
    success,cv2_im = vidcap.read()
    if success == True:
        cv2_im = cv2.cvtColor(cv2_im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        im = Image.fromarray(cv2_im)
        im = im.resize((x_res/rows + x_res%rows, y_res/columns + y_res%columns), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        new_im.paste(im, (x_cntr, y_cntr))
    elif success == False:
        new_im.save('./' + name + ' Output/' + str(x) + '.jpg')
        print str(round(100*(float(x)/frames), 1)) + "% Complete" #Why isn't this 100%, fix
```

As you can see, this specific line for resizing the image (to fit the new array of images) is **exactly the same** in both scripts:

```
im = im.resize((x_res/rows + x_res%rows, y_res/columns + y_res%columns), Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

...Except in the first script, the image is opened from a JPEG, and in the second script, the image is taken from a video frame using OpenCV2. If I try this with a different video, the same thing happens. **It resizes as if I were using `.thumbnail` instead of `.resize`.**

So **why is there a different output** even though they are the same script?

PS: I also don't know why there are more output images on the jpeg script than the video script, but that may be the fault of FreeVideoToJPGConverter (a software); I'm not sure though.